# Why i am getting problem Cannot find module '../src/react/jsx-runtime' from '__tests__/Home.test.tsx' in my test cases?

Tags: next.js, jestjs

`Home.test.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Home from '@/app/page';

describe('Home', () => {
  it('should have Docs text', () => {
    render(<Home />); // ARRANGE

    const myElem = screen.getByText('Docs'); // ACT

    expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument(); // ASSERT
  });

  it('should contain the text "information"', () => {
    render(<Home />); // ARRANGE

    const myElem = screen.getByText(/information/i); // ACT

    expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument(); // ASSERT
  });

  it('should have a heading', () => {
    render(<Home />); // ARRANGE

    const myElem = screen.getByRole('heading', {
      name: 'Learn',
    }); // ACT

    expect(myElem).toBeInTheDocument(); // ASSERT
  });
});
```

[image]

I am getting error like this.

NextJS folder structure:

_*tests*_
.husky
.next
.swc
\node_modules
\public
\src
\app
\page.tsx
\layout.tsx
... other routes
\components
\theme
\utils
\types
.env
.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": [
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "plugin:testing-library/react",
    "plugin:jest-dom/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "React": "readonly"
  },
  "plugins": ["import"],
  "rules": {
    "import/first": "error",
    "import/newline-after-import": "error",
    "import/no-cycle": "off",
    "import/no-duplicates": "error"
  }
}
```

.gitignore
.npmrc
\jest.config.js

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  preset: 'ts-jest',
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(config);
```

\jest.setup.js

```
require('@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect');
```

\next-env.d.ts
\next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  modularizeImports: {
    '@mui/icons-material': {
      transform: '@mui/icons-material/{{member}}',
    },
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

\package.json

```
{
  "name": "next-setup",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prettier": "prettier --write .",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/react": "11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "5.14.19",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.42",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "next": "14.0.3",
    "npm": "^10.2.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0",
    "npm": ">=9.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
    "@types/cypress": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.13.2",
    "cypress": "^13.6.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.3",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-next": "^0.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^6.2.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

\tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./src/*"],
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

you can see all of the source you may check.

I have tried to delete node_modules and caches but it did not help. i tried to reinstall dependencies with older and newer versions. but i did not get anything. Result is 0 (

Comment: Can you provide the GitHub repo?